# For /f and REG QUERY output and parentheses, trying to find JRE home

Tags: java, registry, batch-file

Im trying to write a batch file to find the JRE directory by querying the registry.

I'm using REG QUERY which is returning the following output:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java RuntimeEnvironment\1.6
JavaHome    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6
```

Im then trying to use FOR /F to return the JavaHome value as below:

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3*" %%B IN (`REG QUERY "%JAVA_VERSION%" /v %JAVA_HOME_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
echo %%B)
```

Problem is this returns only c:\Program Files. At first i thought that's fine I just need the next token as its split on the following space but that doesnt work, so Im assuming it's the parentheses that's the problem.

Question is, how do I succesfully retrieve the java path from the reg query output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I misunderstood usage of the tokens parameter. 3* will return consecutively named parameters for each token it finds so in this case i needed to access: %%B and %%C to get the full path.